# multiple model targets are not detected in in vuforia

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I am new to vuforia and unity. When I place two model targets in a unity scene, only the top one is recognized by the ARCamera. I want to add multiple model targets and i want the ARcamera to detect the object it is placed on. Is there a way to do it using code? The videos on Youtube showed SIMULTANEOUS MULTIPLE TRACKED OBJECTS option in VUFORIA CONFIGURATION but i cant see that aswell. I

Answer (score 3):

Vuforia does not support simultaneous activation (and tracking) of multiple Model Targets. This is why only the first one works in your case. If you need to figure out which of a set of models is in front of the camera please look at the Advanced Model Target feature (https://library.vuforia.com/model-targets/advanced-model-target-databases). This automatically detects the model and activates it for tracking.